# ARC error when declaring delegate ivar

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC (no, this is not NDA). I am declaring my ivar in my interface with

```
id itemDelegate;
```

I then declare the property:

`@property (nonatomic, weak) id<mySecretDelegateYouAreNotSupposedToSeeOnSO> itemDelegate;` (with weak instead of assign because of ARC)

In my implementation file I simply synthesize it: `@synthesize itemDelegate;`

However, I am getting the error:

```
"Existing ivar 'ItemDelegate' for _weak property 'itemDelegate' must be _weak".
```

Anyone know what's wrong? Thanks for your help.

ARC - Automatic Reference Counting

Comment: I was able to get rid of my error by changing the line where I synthesize it to: @synthesize itemDelegate = _itemDelegate; to the effect where I call _itemDelegate in my methods now. But does anyone have an explanation for this or a different solution? Thanks again.

Comment: For the modern runtime (iOS 4.0 or later that supports ARC), you don't need to declare ivars at all for properties.

Comment: I am aware that I don't have to declare it (you can just set the property) but I would like to be able to learn "the old way", if you understand me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try something like the following (*example from: http://vinceyuan.blogspot.com/2011/06/wwdc2011-session-323-introducing.html*):

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject {
   __weak id <SomeObjectDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (weak) id <SomeObjectDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Please notice how the ivar is declared.

Comment: I wish I could say that I haven't tried adding _weak before my declaration. However, I tried adding <SomeObjectDelegate>, and I'm now getting the error: "Expected ';' at end of declaration list. Basically, _weak is not recognized.

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure your project is in ARC mode?

Comment: The project was created under ARC (it's definitely using it, the whole project has been written with it so far). I suppose I could continue doing what I'm doing to have a working solution, but I'd like to be able to do it "the right way" and declare it as weak when I declare the ivar.

Comment: Wait, after <SomeObjectDelegate>, does what we give it have to have an asterik? I removed it, and the error count on the line went down. The error is now "Unknown type name '_weak'".

Comment: Objects of the type `id` are generally written without an asterisk because it's a short-hand for `NSobject *` which already contains an asterisk. So objects of the type `id *` would actually be `NSObject **`.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. Any last ideas as far as why it's not recognizing the _weak type? I'm about to give up on it (I do have a workaround).

Comment: Hmm.. the error seems to suggest the compiler thinks it's a type (like `NSString`, `NSNumber`, etc...), not an attribute. Perhaps the `__weak` attribute is written down at the wrong spot?

Comment: Did you try something like this? `@property (nonatomic) __weak id <SomeObjectDelegate> delegate;` I'll check the WWDC video later today if you haven't found a fix yet to see if I can figure out a proper solution.

Comment: I get "Expected ';' at end of declaration list" with that. I appreciate you trying to help me with this, big time.

Comment: Do you think you could send the project you made to dylan [at] dylanreich [dot] com? I downloaded Dev Preview 5, but still doesn't recognize anything ): Thanks for helping, I appreciate it.

Comment: =WOLFGANG= Important note: while you are correct that id-s are written without \*, it is NOT because "id is shorthand for NSObject\*" -- an id is ABSOLUTELY NOT an NSObject* (although the object assigned to it may well be.)  UnixJunkie has a nice explanation here: http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html

Answer (score 9):

With ARC and iPhone Simulator 5.0 the following seems to work just fine (no warnings, etc...):

**SomeObject.h**

```
@class SomeObject;
@protocol SomeObjectDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)someObjectDidFinishDoingSomethingUseful:(SomeObject *)object;
@end


@interface SomeObject : NSObject {
   __unsafe_unretained id <SomeObjectDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SomeObjectDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**SomeObject.m**

```
#import "SomeObject.h"

@implementation SomeObject
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@end
```

Comment: _unsafe_unretained is unrecognized as well... something is up.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 4.2 or 4.1? Xcode 4.1 probably won't recognize `__weak` and `__unsafe_unretained`

Comment: 4.2 (Dev preview 2, shhhhh). It's the newest version, so I don't see why it wouldn't recognize them...

Comment: Weird. I wrote the above code in 4.2 dev preview 4 and it works fine there. The current version is dev preview 5 by the way.

Comment: My bad, it's Dev Preview 4. I forgot I downloaded it. Maybe something didn't get updated in the install. I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: So the project you sent me did, in fact, help me. I did not know you needed *two* underscores... Thanks for all the help (:

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue where, even if you update XCode (4.2+) from the Mac App Store, as Apple requires, it leaves the old version of XCode on your computer. So, if you had XCode pinned to your launchpad, and launch it, you'll get all these errors as noted below. You have to find the newer version of XCode, say by using the Spotlight feature, run it, and then as one of its first tasks, it removes the old version of XCode. Then you have no more errors reporting like this.