# 'Existing ivar 'delegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'delegate' must be __unsafe_unretained

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting the error above, but unsure how to go about fixing it. This is my code:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ColorLineDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)valueWasChangedToHue:(float)hue;

@end

@interface ColorLine : UIButton {

    id <ColorLineDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ColorLineDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ColorLine.h"

@implementation ColorLine

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The error occurs in the synthesize line. I can't find a problem though.

Comment: Turn off ARC and see if your problem goes away.  :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ARC error when declaring delegate ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021852/arc-error-when-declaring-delegate-ivar)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Looks like your project might be using `ARC` then properties should be declared this way:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ColorLineDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)valueWasChangedToHue:(float)hue;
@end

@interface ColorLine : UIButton 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ColorLineDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Comment: darn it.. I was just about to type that (so I instead +1'd your answer). Here's a [potentially duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021852/arc-error-when-declaring-delegate-ivar).

Comment: This fixes my problem, but in another class I have more or less the same code with a delegate, and it doesn't produce this same issue for some reason. Any ideas why this is? I haven't coded with iOS5 before, so this sort of thing is new to me.

Comment: Actually, i was wrong, this doesn't fix my problem. It now just says the same error about the 'weak' property.

Comment: If ARC is used then we must just remove  "{

    id <ColorLineDelegate> delegate;

}
"   and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 53):

Use this syntax:

```
@interface SomeClass  : NSObject {
    id <SomeClassDelegate> __unsafe_unretained  delegate;
}
@property (unsafe_unretained) id <SomeClassDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: I was excited when this initially worked for me, but then I further researched __unsafe_unretained and found this in iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide - http://books.google.com/books?id=1eA2RGmEcSYC&pg=PT165&lpg=PT165&dq=ios+__unsafe_unretained&source=bl&ots=cgiUtaz5E1&sig=lKj2PRn9PBBf2lZRz6S-Ivp3EHE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UfCQT8uuDuaYiAKwiZXlAg&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=ios%20__unsafe_unretained&f=false  Basically, says don't do this.  The note below from Johannes worked great for me in iOS 5.1 with ARC.

Comment: @JasonBub that's fine as long as you're building for iOS 5.0 and above. Unfortunately I need to target iOS 4.0 and above.

Comment: @janBP it work for me, but can you explain why have to use unsafe_unretained ?? thanks

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem when I used old example code which did not feature ARC in my ARC project. It seems that you do not need to put the variable declarations into the interface definition any more. So your code should work like this:

h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ColorLineDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)valueWasChangedToHue:(float)hue;

@end

@interface ColorLine : UIButton {

    // Get rid of this guy!
    //id <ColorLineDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ColorLineDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "ColorLine.h"

@implementation ColorLine

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: It works great for me remove the vars from  interface definition area

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a bit late but to be "ARC compliant", you simply have to replace

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ColorLineDelegate> delegate;
```

by

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <ColorLineDelegate> delegate;
```

Bye.

Comment: This appears solution works very well when I converted legacy code to ark.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a weak property, this also works.

```
@interface MyClass  : NSObject {
    __weak id <MyClassDelegate> _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyClassDelegate> delegate;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
@dynamic delegate
```

in the implementation instead of synthesize.

Comment: This just makes the code crash at run time. If one assigns delegate to self then you get an unrecognised selector error and the program halts.

Comment: you should implement all the protocol methods where you set the delegate or assign these methods optional in delegate class.