# iOS5 ARC errors: SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm attempting to incorporate this [bit of code](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/wiki/GettingStarted) into a new(iOS 5) project... Problem is, I'm using ARC and it REALLY doesn't like the code as written.

I've been able to resolve most of the errors, but I'm stuck with 3 errors I can't seem to figure out.

**Error #1:**

> Existing ivar 'delegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'delegate'
>   must be _unsafe_unretained

.h

```
@interface SKPSMTPMessage : NSObject {  
    NSOutputStream *outputStream;
    NSInputStream *inputStream;

    id <SKPSMTPMessageDelegate> delegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id <SKPSMTPMessageDelegate> delegate;
```

.m

```
@synthesize login, pass, relayHost, relayPorts, subject, fromEmail, toEmail, parts, requiresAuth, inputString, wantsSecure, \
delegate, connectTimer, connectTimeout, watchdogTimer, validateSSLChain;
```

**Errors #2 & #3:**

> Passing address of non-local object to _autoreleasing parameter for
>   write-back

.h

```
@interface SKPSMTPMessage : NSObject {  
    NSOutputStream *outputStream;
    NSInputStream *inputStream;

    id <SKPSMTPMessageDelegate> delegate;
}
```

.m

```
[NSStream getStreamsToHostNamed:relayHost port:relayPort inputStream:&inputStream outputStream:&outputStream];
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138902/existing-ivar-delegate-for-unsafe-unretained-property-delegate-must-be-un

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found right solution for this question.

The answer is: **Dont bother yourself converting code manually.**

You just need to add compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` to imported classes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Error #1**
Replase

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id <SKPSMTPMessageDelegate> delegate;
```

To

```
@property(nonatomic, _unsafe_unretained) id <SKPSMTPMessageDelegate> delegate;
```

You can't use `assign` with ARC

**Error #2,3**
Try to not `alloc` and `init` `outputStream` and `inputStream` variables.

```
NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;
[NSStream getStreamsToHostNamed:relayHost port:relayPort inputStream:&inputStream outputStream:&outputStream];
```

Comment: Thanks... I actually ended up just disabling ARC for that library.

Comment: Whenever I disable ARC for my "SKPSMTPMessage.m" file (presuming disabling is what happens when you add the Compiler Flag "-fno-objc-arc") I just get an Apple Mach-O Linker Error saying there is a duplicate symbol found. Did you have this error? If so how did you get round it?!!? And if not, what am I doing wrong?? Matt