# Arc Error ?? Existing ivar delegate for unsafe_unretained property

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am currently following the tutorials in a book that was written before the use of arc in Xcode. I have the exact same problem like what is stated here:

['Existing ivar 'delegate' for unsafe_unretained property 'delegate' must be __unsafe_unretained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138902/existing-ivar-delegate-for-unsafe-unretained-property-delegate-must-be-un)

The question has been answered, but is has not been stated exactly why this is the case.

The Code in the book states that I use this code to declare member variables:

```
the.h File
___________
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface TestProgramDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
     NSWindow *window;
     NSTextField *message;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *message;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *inputText;
@end


the.m file
__________
#import "the.h" //File

@implementation theHFileAppDelegate

@synthesize window
@synthesize message
@synthesize inputText
```

When I synthesize the variables in my .m file, I get the following error message:
Existing ivar 'window' for property 'window' with assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretaied.

But when I remove the declaration of the member variables like its stated in the book, everything works fine and I don't get an error.

```
the.h File
___________
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface TestProgramDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
     NSWindow *window;
     NSTextField *message;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *message;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextField *inputText;
@end


the.m file
__________
#import "the.h" //File

@implementation theHFileAppDelegate

@synthesize window
@synthesize message
@synthesize inputText
```

My program works, but I want to understand why this causes trouble. Thanks a lot.