# custom viewcontroller delegate not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i'm having issues on my custom delegate, not sure why is not working.i wan to pass the delegate to the mainview so it will auto push to a detail view after adding a new record.

Not sure what i have missed out.i'm doing all the linkage with storyboard & iOS 5.

thanks for looking and appreciated all comments

addnote.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "memoView.h"

@protocol addNoteDelegate;
@interface addNote : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *memoNameTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *memoCommentsTextField;
    id <addNoteDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id <addNoteDelegate> delegate;


- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol addNoteDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)addNoteDidFinish:(addNote *)controller;
-(void)addNoteDidCancel:(addNote *)controller;
@end
```

addnote.m

```
-(IBAction)add:(id)sender
{   
   [[self delegate] addNoteDidFinish:self];
}
```

mainview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "addNote.h"

@interface mainView : UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, addNoteDelegate>
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *memoInfo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *ObjectContext;

-(IBAction)backToMain:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addNote:(id)sender;
@end
```

mainView.m

```
-(IBAction)addNote:(id)sender
{
    addNote *addingNote = [[addNote alloc] init];
    addingNote.delegate = self;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addNote" sender:self];
}

- (void)addNoteDidFinish:(addNote *)controller{
//PUSH TO NEXT VIEW

    [[self navigationController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Where have you set the delegate?

Comment: what do you mean ? i set it in my header file

Comment: That's not setting the delegate. That's just the declaration. There's your problem. If you do not have something in your code as such "mainView.delegate = self;" or similar, then you have not actually set the delegate.

Comment: oh, i forgotten to add in here.
-(IBAction)addNote:(id)sender
{
    addNote *addingNote = [[addNote alloc] init];
    addingNote.delegate = self;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addNote" sender:self];
}
is this the right way ?

Comment: edit it into your post. Also, looks alright at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was missing a function:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addNote"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
        addNote *addingNote = (addNote *)navController.topViewController;
        addingNote.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @protocol addNoteDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)addNoteDidFinish:(addNote *)controller;
-(void)addNoteDidCancel:(addNote *)controller;
@end

@interface addNote : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *memoNameTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *memoCommentsTextField;
    id <addNoteDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id <addNoteDelegate> delegate;


- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
@end
```

and:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

not:

```
[[self navigationController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Be aware if your using ARC you need to check out this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021852/arc-error-when-declaring-delegate-ivar

Comment: Thanks for the reply, hubert.

i moved the 1 to the top but it won't work...the error is "Expected a type"

Comment: Make sure your setting the delegate to the mainView if this is where you want to use it. in the viewDidLoad of mainView: addNote.delegate = self. Remember you have to "assign" it to a Class. In your case it's mainView, the Class that is using it.

Comment: i added this in my mainView.m
-(IBAction)addNote:(id)sender
{
    addNote *addingNote = [[addNote alloc] init];
    addingNote.delegate = self;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addNote" sender:self];
}

Comment: Thanks for the help hubert... i missed out the prepareforSegue which cause it not working....i fixed it now.