# Moving to and fro modal view inside TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

hi i am working on an app and all was going good till now.... i am stuck at this point..
here is my storyboard snapshot..

[image: storyboard]

in the DemoTableViewController when i clock on "filters" button .. Brands TableViewController is opened modally .
after user select multiple rows in Brands TableViewController ,, he then clicks on done button and view controller is dismissed by this code:

```
-(IBAction)DonePressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am storing the user selections in NSMutableSet and it is to be Used in DemoTableViewController so that i can reload the table rows according to the selection but i dont know how to send NSMutableSet to DemoTableViewController and then reload the table according to selection..
what is the right way to dismiss modal view and reload the parent DemoTableViewController
i know i am not doing it correctly but can anyone help me in doing it...
here is some code ---
DemoTVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyModelClass.h"
#import "brandsTableViewController.h"

 @interface demoTableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,MyModelProtocol,FilterProtocol>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *demoTable;
- (IBAction)FilterPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

DemoTVC.m-- 
the method which performs segue--

```
- (IBAction)FilterPressed:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FilterPressed" sender:self];
 }
```

the delegate method which is called to get the values from BrandsTVC--

```
-(void)GetTheSet:(NSMutableSet *)MySet{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

viewdidLoad--

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    productArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    homeModel = [[MyModelClass alloc] init];
    // Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
    homeModel.delegate = self;
    // Call the download items method of the home model object
    [homeModel downloadItemswithurl:@"url is written here"];  
}
```

BrandsTVC.h---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyModelClass.h"

@protocol FilterProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)GetTheSet:(NSMutableSet *) MySet;
@end

@interface brandsTableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,MyModelProtocol>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *RetailerList;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableSet *selectStates;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<FilterProtocol> delegate;
- (IBAction) DonePressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

BrandsTVC.m---

```
@interface brandsTableViewController ()
{
    MyModelClass *myModelClass;
    NSMutableArray *BrandsArray;
    brandsTableViewController *Delegate;
}
 @end
```

viewDidLoad----

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    BrandsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.selectStates=[NSMutableSet new];
    myModelClass = [[MyModelClass alloc] init];
    // Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
    myModelClass.delegate = self;
    // Call the download items method of the home model object
    [myModelClass downloadItemswithurl:@"url to get json"];
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
}
```

Done Button is called ---

```
- (IBAction)DonePressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    id<FilterProtocol> strongDelegate = self.delegate;

    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(GetTheSet:)]) {
            [strongDelegate GetTheSet:self.selectStates];
    }  
}
@end
```

Comment: The proper way is to use delegate. Your DemeTVC is the delegate of BrandTVC. when doneButtonPressed called in BrandTVC, send the selected Brands to the delegate. The delegate then dismissViewController.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers

Comment: i have tried exactly the same but delegate method is not called in after the dismissal of modal view...

Comment: doneButtonPressed should be implemented in BrandTVC, which calls the delegate like [self.delegate didSelectBrand.....], BrandTVC not dismissing the modal. dismissViewController should be called in the didSelectBrand method in DemoTVC.

Comment: ohh now i am gtting the point.. i will try it and reply

Comment: i cant get it working

Comment: Post your code of your new try. Did you set the delegate of destinationViewController in prepareForSegue?

Comment: Hey I have added some code.... take a look at it.. and GetTheSet method in DemoTVC is not being called on pressing Done button

Comment: You did not set the BrandTVC's delegate to be the DemoTVC. You should set it in prepareForSegue

Comment: i cant figure out how to do that..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error i come to know that in BrandsTVC--

```
- (IBAction)DonePressed:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"done pressed %@",self.delegate);
    [delegate GetTheSet:self.selectStates];
}
```

self.delegate is giving me NULL. 
delegate is not setup and i cant figure out how to do that.. someone help me..

this answer solved my problem :D
    [custom viewcontroller delegate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783492/custom-viewcontroller-delegate-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: Congratulation! Glad to hear that you finally get through!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep those elements in NSUserDefaults, and whenever DemoTableViewController appears, you send [tableView reloadData]. Do this in the viewDidAppear: method.

You can also use Core Data, but there are a lot of details to explain how to do that.

Comment: the problem  is i must go back to demoTableViewController and reconnect to server and fetch the contents of selected rows/retailers in modal view...
initially on first loading ,, demo View is showing content from all Retailers

Comment: In the demoTableViewController, when you present the the TableViewController, do like this:

[self presentViewController:demoVC animated:YES completion:^{
            // code to reload data from server...
            // also call [tableView reloadData]; when new data is downloaded...
        }]